# Pausing/Resuming OneDrive syncing with C#

Tags: c#, onedrive

I am looking for a way to set a schedule for OneDrive in a program I am developing. This schedule will only allow OneDrive to sync from midnight (00:00) to  6AM (06:00). The scheduling part of the program I know how to do, the part I am struggling with is finding a way to Pause the Sync at 6 AM and Resume it at midnight.

If someone could help me find a way to programmatically Pause and Resume OneDrive sync I would be grateful.

Comment: removed unwanted text..

Comment: Added OneDrive tag, minor grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are mainly **2 methods** that I would go so far to archive this, let me explain you:

### Sleep the proccess Form CMD

Here it is the command:

```
Invoke-WindowsApi "kernel32" ([bool]) "DebugActiveProcess" @([int]) @(process_id_here)
```

You will have to find the process id First (the program used by OneDrive should be **SkyDrive.exe** and it is under System32) 
  You will also have to **[install Invoke-WindowsApi](http://poshcode.org/2189)** before running that command.

### Shutdown the process and then restart it

You  can **shut down the process** and then restart it at midnight, like this:

```
SkyDrive.exe /shutdown
SkyDrive.exe
```

[image]

You can create a batch for this.

Comment: This will not work as Onedrive automatically restarts the process when you open the folder.